# c# custom attribute- missing boolean parameters default to false?

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

I have a field with a custom attribute on it, that looks like this:

```
[DBDataTypeAttribute(FieldType = "varchar(1000)",AllowNulls=false)]
public String ERLineID;
```

I've got some code that looks for this, like so:

```
foreach (FieldInfo field in userType.GetFields())
{
    currentDefaultDataType = createtabledefaultdatatype;
    currentDefaultAllowNulls = createtabledefaultallownulls;

    DBDataTypeAttribute attribute =
        (DBDataTypeAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field, typeof(DBDataTypeAttribute));

    if (attribute != null)
    {
        // at least one of createtabledefaultdatatype or createtabledefaultallownulls exists
        if (attribute.FieldType != null)
        {
            currentDefaultDataType = attribute.FieldType;
        }
        if (attribute.AllowNulls != null)
        {
            currentDefaultAllowNulls = attribute.AllowNulls;
        }
...
```

The value createtabledefaultallownulls comes from a config file and is set to true.  However I've found when I leave off the 'allownulls' in my attribute, it overwrites my 'true' default with a value of false.

If I specified only the FieldType in my attribute, I would have expected 'if (attribute.AllowNulls != null)' to evaluate false.  Instead, it says that the value isn't null and says that attribute.AllowNulls is false.  So it overwrites my default even though no value was specified.  Is this something to do with bools not being nullable?  Or perhaps if you add an attribute you must explicity define all the parameters within it?

The workaround I'm considering is just making it a string and bool.parsing it, but that doesn't sound very elegant!  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>You need a third state other than true of false, and that would be unset.</strike>

Change AllowNulls to a [Nullable boolean](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), bool?.  AllowNulls will then allow the values of null, true, or false.  If the user does not specify it in the attribute it will be initialized to null.  So your `attribute.AllowNulls != null` will do exactly what you want and users will still be able to set the value to `true` or `false`.

Ok, so you can't use nullables on Attributes.  Didn't know that. You could use something like below rather than changing over to a string, although it isn't that pretty:

```
 private bool? allowNulls = null;
 public bool AllowNulls  {
    get { return allowNulls.GetValueOrDefault(false); }
    set { allowNulls = value; }
 }
 public bool AllowNullsWasSet() { return allowNulls.HasValue; }
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is what I initially thought would be good, but when I change the private/public parts of my attributes to bool? I get an error 'Error 4 'AllowNulls' is not a valid named attribute argument because it is not a valid attribute parameter type'.  This is with attribute declaration:         private bool? allownulls;
        public bool? AllowNulls
        {
            get...

Comment: You're right nullables aren't allow on attributes.  Didn't realize that.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416126/why-is-a-nullablet-not-a-valid-custom-attribute-parameter-when-t-is

Comment: Interesting alternative, thanks for that.  I'll mark this as the answer since it provides alternative code to achieve the desired end.  For my part I'll be going for a string I think!  :)

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am misunderstanding your question, it will always be false unless you initialize it otherwise.  Since bool is a value, it has a default value of false.   So without initialization, it will remain that way.  Also, attribute.AllowNulls != null should not compile, since the value type can never be null.  Null is reserved for reference types, since it is the reference itself that it compares for its check.

Comment: Hi hvie, basically my if statement was trying to see if the attribute had the 'allownulls' value specified for that field.  Given what you've mentioned, is there any way to identify if there's a real 'user specified' value for the boolean?  The attribute.AllowNulls != null does compile, but as you say isn't performing a function.

Comment: I think that you mentioned that you have loaded this from the configuration, so you could make it a string.

Comment: I think you would have to abstract it, then use the constructor of the attribute to set it.  Then you could have another bit that shows that it is set or not.  It is cumbersome unless you use a nullable bool (bool?)

Comment: Maybe that wasn't clear, I would make a property on the attribute so that when you set it, you can also set a bit showing that the value was set and not just defaulted.  That would give you the three states that you are looking for (Not Set, False,True)

Comment: Thanks.  I agree a nullable bool would be the elegant way, unfortunately this creates an error; perhaps nullable bools aren't allowed as parameters to attributes.

Comment: What is the exception that you are getting? I find it hard to believe that any type is not permitted, since the attribute is just a class like any other.  Are you using the HasValue before you access the value?  The real question stands, what is the error, because I am positive that this is not an issue.

Comment: attribute.AllowNulls != null compiles just fine because the it is boxed, but to your point, it will never be null.  It shouldn't be an issue to use bool? but the solution of tracking if the property set it is still much better than the string option.

Comment: Take a look at this post for the deal with the nullable types.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765339/nullable-int-in-attribute-constructor-or-property

Comment: Thanks for all your help.  I think I'll use a string for simplicity.  cheers

Comment: Can I get a nod on my answer?